# Can I have more than one update statement in a single sql task with parameters?

Tags: ssis

Can I put more than one statement in a sql task and will the 2nd statement use the  4th, 5th and 6th parameters values?  I really dont want to create a stored procedure for something like this, and would also rather have just one sql task instead of two

> param1 
> param2 
> param3 
> param4 
> param5 
> param6

```
UPDATE dbo.WhInvoice SET Bal = ?, [Status] = ? WHERE ID = ?
UPDATE dbo.WhInvoice SET Bal = ?, [Status] = ? WHERE ID = ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have as many statements within an Execute SQL Task as you wish.

If you are using a Connection Manager that uses ordinal positions, you'd wire up parameters as shown in your question.

A trick, if you will, that I enjoy is creating variables within my SQL statement and populating them. This allows me to only map a parameter in once and then reuse to my heart's content. For example, let's assume that status value, parameter 2 is assigned to both the first and second statement.

```
DECLARE 
     @Bal1 decimal(18,2) = ?, @Status varchar(30) = ?, @id1 int = ?
,    @Bal2 decimal(18,2) = ?, @id2 int = ?;

UPDATE dbo.WhInvoice SET Bal = @Bal1, [Status] = @Status WHERE ID = @id1;
UPDATE dbo.WhInvoice SET Bal = @Bal2, [Status] = @Status WHERE ID = @id2;
```

Now, I only have to pass in 5 parameters instead of 6. It also makes it easier to test logic in your database as you only have to "fix" the first portion for it be a valid SQL statement.

Comment: @bitshift always follow this tip when writing SSIS SQL commands, it's way easier to maintain and to know which parameter goes where.